# How did Newton compute derivatives by first computing power series?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, soft-question, power-series, math-history

I've read that the way we compute power series these days is not how it was originally done. These days, we compute the derivatives of the function we wish to expand in order to compute the power series. I've heard that this is backwards from the historical development, where one would compute the power series in order to know the derivatives.

How does this work? I believe it has something to do with some sort of iterative method of interpolating polynomials, but I'm not so sure actually. Thank you!

Comment: The binomial expansion was ‘known’ without derivatives id guess. Of course the geometric series too. From these and from naively integrating and differentiating them you get lots of new series like the inverse trigonometric functions and the logarithm

Comment: Newton was able to compute derivatives of arbitrary polynomials by expanding their power series.

Comment: **Polynomials**? The power series of a polynomial is the most trivial of all, not even worth mentioning. Their differentiation is also the most trivial of all. If you don't already know how to differentiate polynomials then you definitely don't know how to differentiate power series

Comment: Newton computed derivatives of polynomials at x=a by computing the power series about x=a WITHOUT first computing the derivatives. It was from the (yes.. finite..) expansion that he was then able to read off the derivatives.